# How to find out what characters you have on what servers?

Tags: conquer-online

I use to play Conquer Online.  I had a total of 5 different accounts. Now that I have come back, I reset back to my permanent email address, an updated all of my account details for my first account. How do I see all the characters that I have for each account? The only way I have seen is to login to every single server with that account, and there are a lot of them. Is there an easier way to see a full list of characters on every server?

Comment: I used to play this game way too much

Comment: Maybe some kind of script can be made that can automate these trys ?